# How to split a String and add to an ArrayCollection

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a string like this:

`var tempSting:String = "abc@abc.com;xyz@xyz.com"`

I want to add this String into the `ArrayCollection`. And the above String should be divided by mail id and remove the `;` symbol and need to add as`ArrayCollection`

`tempAc:Arraycollection = new ArrayCollection{abc@abc.com, xyz@xyz.com}`

Please help me to add the split String into the ArrayCollection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var tempString:String="abc@abc.com;xyz@xyz.com";
var tempArray:Array=tempString.split(";");

//tempAc is a predefined and presumably prepopulated arraycollection    

for each(var email:String in tempArray) {
    tempAc.addItem(email);
}
```

---

**EDIT** Now that I see Shane's answer I must add the following:

This code will append the array to the arraycollection. If you just want to create a new arraycollection, all you need to do is:

```
var tempAc:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection(tempArray);
```

or in 1 line,

```
var tempAc:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection(tempString.split(";"));
```

---

**UPDATE** - to answer questions in the comments:

`tempAc.getItemAt(i)` will give you the email id at the *i* th position

`tempAc.getItemIndex("someone@email.com")` will give you the index at which `someone@email.com` exists in the arraycollection (or -1 if not contained)

`tempAc.contains("someone@email.com")` will return `true` or `false` depending on if the string is contained or not in the arraycollection

So, to check for duplicate ids, all you got to  do is:

```
var newEmailId:String="someone@email.com";
if(!tempAc.contains(newEmailId)) {
    tempAc.addItem(newEmailId);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to do this rather than just passing the tempArray in the ArrayCollection constructor? Honest question, I don't work much with ArrayCollections.

Comment: @shanethehat: Your code will create a new arraycollection. This will then contain only the 2 emails given in tempString. If you have a pre- populated arraycollection, then looping is the way to append the array

Comment: I see, although I think you meant to use a semi-colon rather than a comma in your last code block. +1

Comment: @shanethehat, you're right. I've been working with csv files all day long, that one kinda crept in :) Corrected it now :D

Comment: @Prana: i have one more help.. I had added 2 mail id's to ArrayCollection. if i add one more mail id, i have to check the duplicate list from the arraycollection. can i know how to do this?

Comment: @RaviKChowdary, check my new answer

Comment: @Pranav - I've added you second answer in here, so you can delete it.

Comment: @shanethehat thanks. Weird that I couldn't see the edit link when I tried earlier, maybe someone had locked it?

Answer (score 6):

```
var tempString:String = "abc@abc.com;xyz@xyz.com";
tempAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(tempString.split(";"));
```